# Do I have to refresh Firebase Data everytime I run cellforrow Method?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I have a function that is called RetrievePosts() which observes the Firebase DataBase and gets the values for my model. I run this in viewdidload().

My cellForRow updates the cell's info based on the information retrieved.Pretty standard. However, I have a button on each custom cell that toggle on/off based on like/dislike for button press, and this state change in monitored in the custom cell class and is updated to firebase.

The problem occurs when I scroll the tableview back and forth, the button state goes back to the one that is set from the initial RetrievePost() data.

How should I solve this problem?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when we do not add 'else condition' for the state. For example, if there are 10 data objects, and 5 are visible. When we scroll back and forth the cell are being reused. Now assume that you have liked only one cell. As we scroll back and forth, this cell will be reused for to show other data model, and if you do not give 'else condition' chances are that, the state of some cell shows as liked.

You can get the gist of it from the following code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Identifier") as? CustomCell
    let postModel = postModelArray[indexPath.row]
    if postModel.isLiked {
        cell.likeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Liked")
    } else {
        cell.likeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "NotLiked")
    }
}
```

Comment: where would i update the model to reflect button pressed? in my custom cell class?

Comment: It is better to update it in custom cell itself. While in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, pass the data model to cutsom cell.  Also create an action for Like Button in custom cell. So whenever clicked on Like button, update the model object.

Comment: i figured it out using protocol and delegates , thanks for helping